# Как защитить удаление из SQL

Tags: php, sql

Я хочу удалить определенный элемент из массива, имею следующий PHP код.

```
if (isset($_GET['del_task'])){
        $id = $_GET['del_task'];
        mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM `tasks` WHERE `id`=$id");
        header ('location: panel.php');
    }
```

И элемент на который я жму, чтобы удалить запись

```
<td class='delete'>
  <a href="panel.php?del_task=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">X</a>
</td>
```

Проблема следующая, как мне защитить бд. Ведь сейчас любой, кто введет в адресную строку  например  hostname/del_task=1 удалит элемент из бд.

Comment: Вот и пришло время делать авторизацию для пользователей...

Comment: А если он введет в адресную строку `del_task=1+OR+1%3D1`, то он удалит вообще все записи в таблице. Потому что нельзя подставлять значения переменных непосредственно в текст запроса, необходимо использовать подготавливаемые запросы https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Добавлю, что нельзя вешать операции изменения базы на GET-запросы. Вешайте их на POST. Вместо ссылки нужно будет размесить форму с кнопкой submit, которую пользователь должен будет нажать, чтобы выполнить запрос. А по ссылкам у вас робот может пробежаться, и всё сотрёт.